# Pandas conditional match loop between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(path2)
```

df1c:

```
    date_of_financing
2012-10-01                                                  n/a
2014-06-01                                     NCB, CSC, Health
2014-02-01                            National Cancer Institute
2013-09-01                                                  n/a
2012-09-01                                Maryland Venture Fund
                                    ...
2021-06-01                               Karista and White Fund
2021-07-01                                          Zepp Health

names = ['3E Bioventures', '3SBio', '3V SourceOne Capital',...]

df1['date_of_financing'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_of_financing'])
df1 = df1.set_index('date_of_financing')
df1c = df1.fillna('n/a')
names = df2['investor_name'].unique().tolist()
```

The investor names in df2 where put in a list. I want to iterate the names in df2['investor_name'] list in a column of df1, df1c['lead_investors'], a create a new column df1c['investor_continent'], where for every match I got from df1c and df2, I write in the new column 'asia', in this way:

```
for x in names:  
     match_asia = df1c['lead_investors'].str.contains(x, na=False).any()
     if match_asia > 0:
     df1c['investor_continent'] = 'asia'
```

the loop returns the exact boolean result, but  df1c['investor_continent'] = 'asia' is obviously wrong because it prints 'asia' in every row.

What's the exact way to print 'asia' when there is a match, and 'other' if there is not match?

Comment: Please providde the sample data `df1`, and `df2`

Comment: @ThePyGuy I added df1c and names list taken from df2.

Comment: df1 and df2 not clear, but the key here is pd.merge(), and numpy.where() for the condition

Comment: @Orlando I cannot do a merge since I'm trying to match a df[column] and a list. np.where doesn't return the right results because it requires exact matches that I don't have, str.contains works better for this.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved it with:

```
conditions = list(map(df1c['lead_investors'].str.contains, names))
df1c['continents'] = np.select(conditions, names, 'unknown')
```